# OOP/Python TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop

I am receiving a TypeError: 'float' object is not callable on my Python code? What am I missing? I have fiddled around with it and have not found a solution. I have also browsed all through the different post about it and have not found a solution. At least not one that I recognized or understood.

```
class MathDojo(object):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.results = 0

    def add(self, *args):
        for i in args:
            if type(i) == list or type(i) == tuple:
                for v in i:
                    self.results += v
            else:
                self.results += i
        return self

    def subtract(self,*args):
        for i in args:
            if type(i) == list or type(i) == tuple:
                for v in i:
                    self.results -= v
            else:
                self.results -= i
        return self

    def results(self):
        print self.results
        return self

md = MathDojo()
md.add([1], 3,4).add([3,5,7,8], [2,4.3,1.25]).subtract(2, [2,3], [1.1,2.3]).results()
```

Comment: One replacement: you can use `if isinstance(i, (list, tuple))`.

Comment: The traceback should include the line number where you attempted to call a float, can you include that?

Comment: remove the `()` at the end - `results` is an attribute, not a method

Comment: @Nick - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mathDojo.py", line 29, in <module>
    md.add([1], 3,4).add([3,5,7,8], [2,4.3,1.25]).subtract(2, [2,3], [1.1,2.3]).results()
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

Comment: You have results set as an attribute and then as a method later on.

Comment: Ah, as @Wondercricket pointed out, you're overwriting the results method right in the `__init__`, so the function gets replaced by 0.

Comment: @Wondercricket - I tried that and when I do it comes up with zero results? No errors but no answers as well

Comment: Methods and attributes share the same namespace (indeed, methods are just a special kind of attribute). Pick a different name for the value initialized in `__init__`.

Comment: Great, thanks all for the help! I changed one of the results and all is good.Always the little things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an attribute `results` created in `__init__` and a method later named the same thing that attempts to call the attribute.  Rename one or the other such as below, where I used an underscore to denote the attribute.

Also:

- You don't need `*args` in `__init__`
- Use `if isinstance(i, (list, tuple))` to check for multiple types

Code:

```
class MathDojo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._results = 0

    def add(self, *args):
        for i in args:
            if if isinstance(i, (list, tuple)):
                for v in i:
                    self._results += v
            else:
                self._results += i
        return self

    def subtract(self,*args):
        for i in args:
            if if isinstance(i, (list, tuple)):
                for v in i:
                    self._results -= v
            else:
                self._results -= i
        return self

    def results(self):
        print(self._results)
        return self

md = MathDojo()
md.add([1], 3,4).add([3,5,7,8], [2,4.3,1.25]).subtract(2, [2,3], [1.1,2.3]).results()
28.149999999999995
```

Comment: It's the other way around. The class has an attribute named `results` (a callable one). Each time you create a new instance, you shadow the class attribute with an instance attribute by the same name to store an number.